# ST_Boundary for Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle, gis, spatial, oracle-spatial

Is it possible to do the equivalent of ST_Boundary with Oracle Spatial? As in get a LINESTRING/MULTILINESTRING from a POLYGON, or a MULTIPOINT from a LINESTRING?

I know the other vendors support it:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stboundary-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get boundary, please see [SDO_UTIL.POLYGONTOLINE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-E431B76C-5629-414E-B01C-A86DDEF2D3E5)

There is not a built in fn for linestring to multipoint. But here is a simple fn to do it (assuming 2D):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multipoint_from_line (line_geom SDO_GEOMETRY)
   RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE IS

   multipoint SDO_GEOMETRY := NULL;
BEGIN
   IF line_geom IS NOT NULL
   THEN
     multipoint := line_geom;

     IF multipoint.sdo_ordinates.count = 0
     THEN
       multipoint := NULL;
     ELSE
       multipoint.sdo_gtype := 2005;
       multipoint.sdo_elem_info := 
sdo_elem_info_array(1,1,multipoint.sdo_ordinates.count/2);
     END IF;
   END IF;

   return multipoint;
END;
/

-- Calling from SQL
SELECT multipoint_from_line 
(sdo_geometry(2002,4326,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),sdo_ordinate_array(0,0,1,1,3,3)))
FROM dual;

-- Calling from PL/SQL
DECLARE
   multipoint SDO_GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
   multipoint := multipoint_from_line 
(sdo_geometry(2002,4326,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),sdo_ordinate_array(0,0,1,1,3,3)));
END;
/
```